# Is there a way to join 2 pandas dataframes based on similar elements in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes with columns consist of news headers, date and lists of keywords (actually, NERs), extracted from the header. And I want to join this two tables based on the similarity of the keywords. And I mean not exact similarity, but similar meaning, like `Washington D.C. = The Capital of the US`. Is there any way I can do this?
I've tried to show what I want in the example below.

Example:

```
table 1

        Header1        Date          NER
481247 Some text here  01.01.2021    [president, Washington D.C.]
481247 Another header  05.03.2021    [London, Darwin]
481248 Header          13.03.2021    [Facebook, Zuckerberg]

table 2

       Header2                  Date          NER
57864 Different header here     01.01.2021    [White House, Biden]
57865 Other header              22.01.2021    [Tesla, Elon]
57866 Another different header  05.03.2021    [Charles Darwin]

Resulting table

Header1         Date       NER                           Header2                   Date        NER     
Some text here  01.01.2021 [president, Washington D.C.]  Different header here     01.01.2021  [White House, Biden]
Another header  05.03.2021 [London, Darwin]              Another different header  05.03.2021  [Charles Darwin]
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.concat will allow you to align dataframes based on the dates, or any other column that matches exactly (your similar keyword request is different). If you make the dates the index, then pass the two dataframes to pd.concat, the columns with common dates will be placed side by side

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"ChipID":["A1","B2","C3","E5"],"something":[2,3,4,54]}

data2 = {"ChipID":["A1","B1","C3","D4","E5"],"something else":[5,3,23,6,5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

############ SET INDEX ############
df1 = df1.set_index("ChipID")
df2 = df2.set_index("ChipID")

df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,sort=False)
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if I want to concat columns, values in which do not match exactly but within their meaning?